# Compensate acceleration changes in a load cell's readings using an accelerometer

Tags: physics, sensors, accelerometer, weighting

I'm reading weight with a load cell that's fixed on a moving body. Said body drives arround many uneven trails. I've tried using an accelerometer to compensate the vertical acceleration, making it so that the normal force is always 9.8 * mass, but that doesnt seem to work, as my results still get lots of noise due to the load cell jumping up and down when the transport body hits a bump.
The accelerometer I'm using is also a gyroscope, and it provides me acceleration readings on the X,Y and Z axis, aswell as angular velocity, roll, pitch and yawn angles.

I've tried using a correction factor to smooth the curve, something like
weight = bruteiweight * 9.8/Ay
where Ay is the vertical acceleration, which reads 9.8m/s² when the accelerometer is siting still on a flat surface.
I expected this factor to compensate the "noise", but it didnt work at all.